# CefSharp Project exe dont open

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

If I use anything with CefSharp in my WPF application, be it "`<cefSharp: ChromiumWebBrowser />`" in the *XAML file* or "`ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser ();`" or "`Cef.Initialize (new CefSettings ());`" in the *.cs file*, I can no longer open the exe in the /obj folder.
The exe in the /bin folder, which is the same, the Visual Studio opens but runs without problems.

I use Visual Studio 2019 (Community).

Via Nuget I installed *CefSharp.Common*, *CefSharp.Wpf*, *cef.redist.x64* and *cef.redist.x84*.
This error occurs with **x64**, **x86**, or **Any CPU**. (For Any CPU I have changed corresponding files (as in: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application))

Comment: So the browser works if run from your bin folder? The exe in your object folder whilst the same won't have the required resources in the obj folder. This is expected, not clear what the problem is if any.

Comment: The Obj folder belongs to the compiler / linker. It is not meant for you to try to do anything with the files that are in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been dealing with a very similar problem for some time. Turns out I just had to delete the three `CefSharp.*.dll` files present in the main directory and instead copy `/x84` folder from `/bin`.

Comment: Do you mean x64? Or x86? x84 looks like a typo. Copy the folder where exactly?